# if a person do a job secretly by violating rules of government, is income via this job is halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram

My question is that If a person do a job on study visa while studying, and government does not allow job on study visa, but he violate the law and do job secretly, is income via this job is halal or haram????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are required to follow the law as a Muslim, so long as the law doesn't contradict with Islamic rulings. Therefore violation of the law is haram and the income received from this job is haram as well.